# Flutter showDialog, AlertDialog background gradient.

Tags: dart, flutter

For color, I can use `dialogBackgroundColor` property to give `AlertDialog` background my own color.

I was looking to use `Gradient` as my background. How can I use that? `DecoratedBox` is something that will be needed, but I don't know what to wrap in what. Can anyone give me idea or link for the same?

Comment: If you are using only `content` without `title` in `AlertDialog` - then you can wrap content in `Container` with gradient background

Comment: I am using Title too. So, it won't work in my case. Now I can also change the content to have title there. But again I was looking for some better solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a Container inside which will be decorated with gradient. For example:

```
class GradientDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _GradientDialogState();
  }
}

class _GradientDialogState extends State<GradientDialog> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            gradient: new LinearGradient(
                colors: AppColors.BG_GRADIENT,
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter)),
        child: YourContentInside(),

      ),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    );
  }
}
```

Open it with

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return GradientDialog();
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

In `build` method of `AlertDialog` there is `return Dialog(child: dialogChild, shape: shape);`. In `Dialog.build()` - it returns `Material(color: _getColor(context), ...`. There is no way to set gradient background for `AlertDialog` without customization.

I can add example if it'll be needed.

P.S. Or you can call `showDialog` and send another widget instead of `AlertDialog`.